# Stale cache issue

Tags: java, caching, redis

I have a web application deployed on 3 servers behind a load balancer. The 3 servers write to the same db. I want to add a Redis cache to the ecosystem and need guidance on how to do that. My initial idea was to start an instance of the cache on each server, but this will be problematic when one server updates the db and its cache - the remaining 2 caches will be stale / out of synch.

I'm new to caching but I've heard to I can create a Redis cluster.

What is the best solution to this? Is my cluster idea the best? Would it work?

Answer (score 0):

You only need one instance of Redis, and the 3 application servers share this single cache.

If the cached data set is small enough to fit into the memory of a single machine, you don't need a Redis Cluster. Otherwise, you can use a cluster to shard the data set to multiple machines.

Comment: How would that architecture look? Would I have Redis installed on only one of my 3 servers and have the other 2 point to it?

Comment: Yes. In order to make it more robust, you can install 2 other Redis instances on other servers, and make these 2 Redis slaves of the master Redis. See [Redis doc](https://redis.io/topics/replication) for more information  on replication.

Comment: I experimented with your replication idea but see that slaves nodes cannot be written to. I managed to get replication happening but I need all nodes to be writeable. I'll eventually go with the shared single instance cache but I need an interim solution because my data is now in 2 stale caches.

Comment: NO. You should NOT write to slaves. Slaves will sync data from master automatically. Slaves are used to ensure that when the master is down, one of the slaves can become the new master. Also you can use slaves to do load balance when there're too many read request, although read from slaves might get stale data.

Comment: Fair point. My solution: stop the cache on 2/3 nodes and leave cache running on 1 node. Point the 2 non-cache nodes to the node that has the cache. If the node_with_cache goes down, the 3 apps will go straight to the db, by-passing the cache. I will add a Geneos monitoring system to alert me that the cache is down and I will restart it, flushing it as it will be stale.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much traffic you have from all those 3 app-servers to redis. You can simply install redis instance outside these 3 app-servers and allow traffic from these 3 app servers. this will be better to scale and loosely couple from other instances.